# can not play youtube embeded videos

Tags: android, youtube

Since 2 days i am trying to run youtube embeded video in my application but i didn't sucessed.
I have used everything whatever i get from stack overflow and other websites.

1. I tried these things with my Samsung Y duos with android 2.3.6 version

   I set the following properties in in the webview settings

   - javascriptEnabled
   - pluginEnable
   - pluginState
   - cacheMode
   - allowContentAccess
   - appCachePath
   - and    finally I    implement a    webViewClient of the    webView as
     well as    override    its       shouldOverrideUrlLoading    method.

Result - I got the first page of the video in my player but when i run that i got black screen in my player.

2-   I also open the video in the iframe what youtube provide to run embeded videos.

Result - I got the same result as stated above

3-   I also used android:hardwareAccelerated="true" in my manifest but it didn't work.

4-   I also run this video using VideoPlayer class.

Result :  I got message like this video cannot be played.In our android application we are using default video player to run videos and our default video player in Samsung Y and Samsung Y Duos  is not supporting youtube embed video. This may be the reason.

5- I have also tried with html page in my assest folder and used embeded code inside my html and open this page in webview but i the front page of the video and when i play it i get blank window.

please help me to solve this problem. Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Which format of video r u trying to play??MAke sure r u playing video of format which is supported by android.See this link may be helpful for u..-"developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html"

Comment: I am playing this http://www.youtube.com/embed/WJzE0_aJx2I and this has h263 format